# Devexpress eXpressApp listview reading pane

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

We are working on an internal issue tracker-like software. When I select an issue in its list view control, I would like to display a reading pane at the bottom to show its details, comments, attached files, etc. (Similar to reading pane of e-mails in Outlook.)

What is the best way to achieve this using DevExpress' eXpressApp framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to turn on the ListViewAndDetailView mode as it is shown in our documentation:

[Display a Detail View Together With a List View](http://documentation.devexpress.dev/#Xaf/CustomDocument2756)

One more solution is to show a control and a text as it is implemented in the FeaturesCenter demo.  Finally, please also refer to the [How to show a hint panel in an XAF Windows Forms application](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E1148)